# POP desktop : What is this 'gjs' process which taking up so much memory and cpu?

Tags: 20.04, desktop-environments, cpu, fan

I have installed `pop-desktop` on my Ubuntu 20.04 and found that the environment is way faster, smoother than my past GNOME Shell. What is odd is that, there is a process named `gjs` and its taking up nearly 90% of my cpu and memory. This is my `top` command:

[image]

This is odd. Because, whenever some process starts using up that much cpu, I can litterally hear my cpu fan roaring at the back of my laptop. With this `gjs` process, this seems to appear not happening. No cpu fan speed change indication. So, is this some wrong reporting, or is it that the `gjs` is indeed killing my cpu? Should I leave `pop-desktop` environment being a 8GB RAM+512GB SSD system?

Comment: If you quite Chrome, or any Java application that you have running, does gjs CPU usage go away?

Comment: @heynnema: `gjs` processes cpu percentage appears to be not changing while I am quiting any of the chrome/java applications

Comment: Try [disabling all the extensions](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/id3uu2/comment/g26lhtc/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) and then enabling one by one to find the culprit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> POP desktop : What is this 'gjs' process which taking up so much memory and cpu?

`gjs` is the **G**nome **J**ava**S**cript engine that plugins run on.

> So, is this some wrong reporting,

Unlikely. It probably is using up 99% CPU, but the fans only become active if a temperature threshold is reached. Could be a decently coded piece of software.

> or is it that the gjs is indeed killing my cpu?

Ehm, what do you mean by "killing"? Using 99% is not "killing" a CPU. It is using your CPU.

> Should I leave pop-desktop environment being a 8GB RAM+512GB SSD system?

That is asking for opinions and for you to decide. Mind that gjs is probably part of any default gnome (3) desktop. Budgie does not have it.

Answer (score -1):

I am a not so skilled user, and I tried many things to try resolving this. The oprtion I found was to remove gjs (sudo apt remove gjs) which will also remove gnome, and then installed the gnome (sudo install gnome). After this, it seems the system is working properly. I will come back if the problem persists.

Comment: It is not clear which version of Ubuntu you are using and if you are using the Pop-Desktop. So, i don't know if this answer answers the question.